# How can you close a modal from a child component without having included the modal in the HTML of the parent component? Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I have a parent component with a button. When I click on the button then a modal is opened. This modal is created with the '@ionic/angular' framework. In the modal is another child component with a form and an update button. When I click on the update button then I want the modal to close.

Parent Component HTML

```
   <ion-buttons>
      <ion-button class="button-green" style="font-size: 70%;"
          (click)="openUpdateModal(value)">Update
      </ion-button>
   </ion-buttons>
```

parent component ts

```
 async openUpdateModal(value: any) {
    console.log(this.columns);
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: ModalGenericPutComponent,
      componentProps: {
        tableName: this.tableName,
        schemaName: this.schemaName,
        columns: this.columns,
        //updateParameter
        id: value.id,
      }
    });
    console.log(modal);
    modal.onDidDismiss()
    .then(() => {
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Modal HTML

```
<app-json-form-update [jsonFormData]="formData" [tableName]="tableName" [schemaName]="schemaName" [id]="id" (buttonClicked)="parentEventHandlerFunction($event)"></app-json-form-update>
  <ion-button expand="block" color="danger" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</ion-button>
</ion-content>
{{valueEmittedFromChildComponent}}
```

Modal TS

```
export class ModalGenericPutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() closeModalEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  valueEmittedFromChildComponent = '';

  parentEventHandlerFunction(valueEmitted){
    this.valueEmittedFromChildComponent = valueEmitted;
  }
  closeModal() {
    this.closeModalEvent.emit(true);
}
```

Form-Child-Component TS

```
 @Output() public buttonClicked = new EventEmitter();
 
clickButton(){
    this.buttonClicked.emit('CLOSE_PARENT_MODAL');
  }
```

I have learned how to send data from a child component to a parent component. It seems that the child component has to be called in the HTML code of the parent component, like here for example:
<app-json-form-update [jsonFormData]="formData" [tableName]="tableName" [schemaName]="schemaName" [id]="id" (buttonClicked)="parentEventHandlerFunction($event)">

However, I am not calling my modal for the HTML code of my parent component. Now I don't know how to give the command from the modal that the modal should be closed.

Does anyone have any advice for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: inside `closeModal()` use `ModalController` for example: `this.modalCtrl.dismiss()`;

Comment: Okay that works. Additionally I had to call the more triggered by the event. Thanks a lot